# Why is GetEnumerator not visible in COM for .Net classes that inherit from IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, com, ienumerable

I'm currently trying to make a C# API visible in COM and I'm currently stuck on making the non generic `GetEnumerator` method visible in COM for classes that also inherit `IEnumerable<T>`. If I implement another method on the `ITestIEnumerable`, it is visible. I've also found that non generic `GetEnumerator` methods are visible on classes that derive from Lists.

I don't really understand why this isn't working, it seems to be a special case for classes that inherit `IEnumerable<T>`. Is there anyway to expose this to COM so I can use the For Each construct in VB6?

For example

```cs
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("Test")]
[Guid("1aa2bdec-0530-44e8-b62d-b75914a6de22")]
public class TestIEnumerable : ITestIEnumerable
{
    #region IEnumerable<Item> Members

    [ComVisible(false)]
    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region ITestIEnumerable Members

    [DispId(-4)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    IEnumerator ITestIEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    [DispId(-4)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("187f3fed-9d4a-4a52-9a7c-a2fdeb56b9fa")]
[ComImport]
public interface ITestIEnumerable : IEnumerable<Item>
{
    [DispId(-4)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    new IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: You are helping too much.  Remove ITestIEnumerable and just have the class implement IEnumerable<>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one public method of the same name with the same signature. As such, two of your `GetEnumerator` methods are being implemented using explicit interface implementation:

```
IEnumerator ITestIEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
}
```

As such, they're treated as private members - it's not even visible to other .NET code unless that code casts your `TestIEnumerable` object to `ITestIEnumerable`.

So, decide which one of your `GetEnumerator()` methods you wish to expose, and make it public:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
}
```

And switch the generic one to an explicit implementation:

```
IEnumerator<Item> IEnumerable<Item>.GetEnumerator()
{
}
```

Comment: I don't know about COM, but in regular .NET it would be more common to expose the generic version on the public API, and keep the non-generic version as the explicit implementation - as per the OP's original code

Comment: @MarcGravell - I think I'd agree with you there - if you're building something for both .NET and COM users, I'd probably make a more conventional .NET class and then some facade classes to expose the functionality to COM as required.

Comment: Thanks guys, the solution was to remove the interface and make the IEnumerator GetEnumerator() public. Solved.